# Chain Of Responsibility- Servicer1 not calling Servicer2

Tags: c#, chain-of-responsibility

I am trying to demonstrate use of chain of responsibility pattern by searching characters/ string inside Servicer class strings. The code runs but Servicer1 ServiceReq is not calling Servicer2 ServiceReq. If I run this with "g", I get"Checked Servicer1'" only but I should get "Checked Servicer1'" "Request found in Servicer 2".

```
MainApp.cs
namespace ChainOfResponsibility
{
    abstract class Servicer
    {
        protected Servicer successor;

        public void SetSuccessor( Servicer s)
        {
            successor = s;
        }
        public abstract string ServiceReq(char request);
    }

    class Servicer1 : Servicer
    {
        public override string ServiceReq(char request)
        {
            string s1 = "Sam ate nuts";
            if (s1.Contains(request))
            {
                return "Request found in Servicer 1";
            }
            else if (successor != null)
            {
                successor.ServiceReq(request);
            }
            return "Checked Servicer1'";
        }
    }

    class Servicer2 : Servicer
    {
        public override string ServiceReq(char request)
        {
            string s2 = "Apples are great";
            if (s2.Contains(request))
            {
                return "Request found in Servicer 2";
            }
            else if (successor != null)
            {
                successor.ServiceReq(request);
            }
            return "Checked Servicer 2";
        }
    }
```

Form Code:

```
namespace ChainOfResponsibility
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            char request = System.Convert.ToChar(textBox1.Text);
            Servicer h1 = new Servicer1();
            Servicer h2 = new Servicer2();
            h1.SetSuccessor(h2);

            AddToList(h1.ServiceReq(request));
        }
        private void AddToList(string message)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(message);

            listBox1.Items.Add("----------------------------------------");

            if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
                listBox1.TopIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried and your expected outcome

Comment: What is the input you're providing through the form? Also, your expected output can never happen; you call `successor.ServiceReq`, but never do anything with the return value.

Comment: You call `successor.ServiceReq(request);` but do nothing with the value returned.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you never do anything with the return value of `successor.ServiceReq`. The next problem is that you seem to want multiple messages returned from `ServiceReq`. To do this, you should make the return type `IEnumerable<string>`, and make corresponding adjustments to your code.

Here is how you would adjust your "servicers":

```
abstract class Servicer
{
    ...
    public abstract IEnumerable<string> ServiceReq(char request);
}

class Servicer1 : Servicer
{
    public override IEnumerable<string> ServiceReq(char request)
    {
        string s1 = "Sam ate nuts";
        yield return "Checked Servicer1";
        if (s1.Contains(request))
        {
            yield return "Request found in Servicer 1";
        }
        else if (successor != null)
        {
            yield return successor.ServiceReq(request);
        }
    }
}

// Similar changes for Servicer2
```

And here are the changes to your form code:

```
namespace ChainOfResponsibility
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ...
        private void AddToList(IEnumerable<string> messages)
        {
            listBox1.Items.AddRange(messages);

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the list containing your expected output, provided you've entered the appropriate character in the textbox.